Using @extends in Laravel Blade adds an extra space on my blade template
Here's my code.
base.blade.php
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                   @yield('content')
                </div>
            </div>

roles.blade.php
@extends('layouts.dashboard.base')
@section('content')
@endsection

when i inspect element

Try adding an inline style to the code for testing, set padding-top and mergin-top to 0 in the first div tag, then run the program, you can also try testing the second div if the first didn't solve your problem.
then if it's fixed, remove the inline css and update your container-fluid class in the css file by add the properties. Here is a modify code to test.
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px">
    <!-- also you can try it here -> style="margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px" -->
    <div class="row">    
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</div>

